# Код работает не так, как надо на javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Посмотрел ролик у Web Developer Blog по создании простенькой игры, но почему - то не работает код на js. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Av53VJI-UiE - ссылка на ролик. Код написан на Javascript, Css и Html. Если вкратце, то игра должна работать по типу динозаврика из хрома, но мой динозаврик ни прыгает, ни умирает.

```js
const dino = getElementById('dino')
const cactus = getElementById('cactus')

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    jump()
})

function jump () {
    if (dino.classList != 'jump') {
        dino.classList.add('jump')
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        dino.classList.remove('jump')
    }, 300)
} 

let isAlive = setInterval(function() {
    let dinoTop = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(dino).getPropertyValue('top'))
    let cactusLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(cactus).getPropertyValue('left'))

    if (cactusLeft < 50 && cactusLeft > 0 && dinoTop >= 140) {
        alert('Game Over')
    }
}, 10)
```

```css
.game {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    margin: auto;
}
#dino {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(images/dino.png);
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
}
#cactus {
    width: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url(images/cactus.png);
    background-size: 20px 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: 110px;
    left: 580px;
    animation: cactusMov 1s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes cactusMov {
    0% {
        left: 580px;
    }
    100% {
        left: -20px;
    }
}
.jump {
    animation: jump 0.3s linear;
}
@keyframes jump {
    0% {
        top: 150px;
    }
    20% {
        top: 130px;
    }
    50% {
        top: 80px;
    }
    80% {
        top: 130px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 150px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>dino rex game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dino.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="game">
        <div id="dino"></div>
        <div id="cactus"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dino.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: const dino = getElementById('dino') `const dino = document.getElementById('dino')`

Comment: извините, поправил ошибку в описании проблемы, перечитайте пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

У вас в коде написано `const dino = getElementById('dino')` должно быть `const dino = document.getElementById('dino');` и в коде нет остановки анимации.. Немного дописал. Поставил кнопку старт/стоп и сделал остановку анимации при столкновении.

```js
const dino = document.getElementById('dino');
const cactus = document.getElementById('cactus');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const out = document.getElementById('out');
const diff = document.getElementById('diff');

let bezie = [
  'cubic-bezier(0.5,0.5,0.7,0.5)',
  'cubic-bezier(0.35,0.7,0.9,0.7)',
  'cubic-bezier(0.25,0.4,0.2,0.3)',
  'cubic-bezier(0.7,0.4,0.4,0.7)'
]
let isAlive = gameStart();
let loots = 0;
let f = false;

btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  btn.value == "Stop" ? stop() : isAlive = gameStart();
  this.blur();
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  jump();
});

function jump () {
  if (dino.classList != 'jump') { 
      dino.classList.add('jump');
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
      dino.classList.remove('jump');
  }, 300)
}
function gameStart () {
  btn.value = "Stop";
  btn.style.background = "green";
  cactus.style.animationPlayState = 'running'; 
  return setInterval(checking, 10);
}
function checking() {
  let dinoTop = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(dino).getPropertyValue('top'))
  let cactusLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(cactus).getPropertyValue('left'))
  if (!f && cactusLeft > 50) f = true;
  if (cactusLeft < 0 && f){
    f = false; 
    changeMover();
  }
  if (cactusLeft < 50 && cactusLeft > 0 && dinoTop >= 140) {
     stop();
     gameOver();       
  }
}
function stop(){
  btn.value = "Start";
  btn.style.background = "red";
  cactus.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
  clearInterval(isAlive);
}
function gameOver () {
  out.style.border = "";
  out.innerHTML = "loots: 0";
  dino.style.background = 'radial-gradient(white, black)';
  alert('Game Over\nYour loots: ' + loots);
  loots = 0;
}
function changeMover(){
  let idx = diff.options.selectedIndex;
  let val = diff.options[idx].value;
  let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * val);
  cactus.style.animationTimingFunction = bezie[i];
  reward( lootCount (val) );
}
function lootCount (val) {
  loots++;
  out.innerHTML = "loots: " + loots;
  if(val == 1){
    return [15,20,25,30]
  }
  if(val == 2){
    return [10,15,20,25]
  }
  if(val == 5){
    return [5,10,15,20]
  }
}
function reward (count){
  if(loots == count[0]) {
    out.style.border='groove';
    dino.style.background = 'radial-gradient(#E664C7, black)';
  }
  if(loots == count[1]) {
    out.style.border='double';
    dino.style.background = 'radial-gradient(#77EAC7, black)';
  }
  if(loots == count[2]) {
    out.style.border='inset';
    dino.style.background = 'radial-gradient(#6EEA12, black)';
  }
  if(loots == count[3]) {
    out.style.border='outset';
    dino.style.background = 'radial-gradient(#EAF64A, black)';
  }
}
```

```css
.game {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    margin: auto;
}
#cont{
  width:50%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#diff{
  top: 30px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#btn{
  width: 55px;
  top: 30px;
  background: green;
  right: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#out{
  top: 30px;
  color: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#dino {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: radial-gradient(white, black);
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
}
#cactus {
  width: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  background: radial-gradient(green, black);
  background-size: 20px 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: 110px;
  left: 580px;
  animation: cactusMov 1.5s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5,0.5,0.7,0.5);
}
@keyframes cactusMov {
  0% {
      left: 580px;
  }
  100% {
      left: -20px;
  }
}
.jump {
  animation: jump 0.3s linear;
}
@keyframes jump {
  0% {
      top: 150px;
  }
  20% {
      top: 130px;
  }
  50% {
      top: 80px;
  }
  80% {
      top: 130px;
  }
  100% {
      top: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>dino rex game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dino.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id= "cont">
      <select size="1" id="diff">
        <option value="1" selected>easy</option>
        <option value="2" >midle</option>
        <option value="5" >hard</option>
      </select>
      <div id="out">loots: 0</div>      
      <input id="btn" type="button" value="Stop">
    </div>
    
    <div class="game">
      <div id="dino"></div>
      <div id="cactus"></div>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dino.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```